# net-snmp agentx re-enable

Tags: net-snmp

I have embedded a net-snmp agentx subagent in my c++ application code on Ubuntu Linux. I want to disable the agentx subagent once it is working and then re-enable it again. I am successfully able to setup the agent, poll the mib using snmpget from the command line and disable agentx socket connection by using snmp_shutdown but I am unable to re-enable the socket connection again once I disable it.

Appreciate any help/pointers.

I use the following code to initialise the SNMP library and the agentx socket connection.

In the beginning, initialise the AgentX subagent -

```
netsnmp_ds_set_boolean(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_ROLE, 1);
        netsnmp_ds_set_int(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_AGENTX_PING_INTERVAL, 120);
        netsnmp_ds_set_string(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_X_SOCKET, m_agentx_socket.c_str());


/* initialize the agent library */
init_agent("MyApp");
// initialise MIB module
init_snmp("MyApp");
```

The poll the MIB using snmpget and disable the connection using the function below -

```
snmp_shutdown("MyApp");
SOCK_CLEANUP;
```

Works fine so far.

Then I re-enable the connection using the code below but this does not work.

```
netsnmp_ds_set_boolean(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_ROLE, 1);
        netsnmp_ds_set_int(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_AGENTX_PING_INTERVAL, 120);
        netsnmp_ds_set_string(NETSNMP_DS_APPLICATION_ID, NETSNMP_DS_AGENT_X_SOCKET, m_agentx_socket.c_str());


/* initialize the agent library */
init_agent("MyApp");
init_snmp("MyApp");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to re-run binary itself after it got shut down.
You have not clarified here why you want to restart agentx.
if you are doing this for  fetching some data frequently. than I guess you can try infinite for loop with sleep command of a time span in your code. this will be better option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following information in the README.agentx file from net-snmp-5.7.2 (currently visible at http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/README.agentx.html :

> Similarly, a subagent will not be able to re-register in place of a
>   defunct colleague until the master agent has received three requests
>   for the dead connection (and hence unregistered it).

It seems likely, therefore, that the master still has your subagent registered despite your attempt at a clean shutdown.  Perhaps you could try making three or more requests while your subagent is disabled and then proceeding with your re-registration.